# Implement search textField into jTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield, rowfilter

Now I have a search textField implemented with KeyReleased event, which don't found/update jTable when I start typing for example "An" from "Andrew", and just after I finish to type exactly (caseSensitive) the name which I want to find.

So, what I want is to implement the Filtering method from this [site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) but I have big problems. After below implementation and removing the "old" KeyReleased event, when I type something in textfield "txt_search" nothing happens with jTable.

My code of table generated by IDE (NetBeans) is (copied from customize code panel):

```
Table_Employee = new javax.swing.JTable();

Table_Employee.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
    new Object [][] {
        {null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null}
    },
    new String [] {
        "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
    }
)
);

Table_Employee.setToolTipText("Employee info table");

Table_Employee.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));

Table_Employee.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);

Table_Employee.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        Table_EmployeeMouseClicked(evt);
    }
});
Table_Employee.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
        Table_EmployeeKeyPressed(evt);
    }
});

jScrollPane1.setViewportView(Table_Employee);
```

and I added this on my panel class where table is:

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.text.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;


public class Employee_info extends javax.swing.JFrame {
Connection conn=null;
ResultSet rs=null;
PreparedStatement pst=null;
private TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> sorter;
    /**
     * Creates new form Employee_info
     */
    public Employee_info() {
        initComponents();
        conn=javaconnect.ConnecrDb();
        Update_table();
        Fillcombo();
        currentDate();
        Table_Employee.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        Table_Employee.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        Table_Employee.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);


        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        sorter = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(model);
        Table_Employee = new JTable(model);


        txt_search = new JTextField();
        //Whenever filterText changes, invoke newFilter.
        txt_search.getDocument().addDocumentListener(
                new DocumentListener() {
                    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                        newFilter();
                    }
                    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                        newFilter();
                    }
                    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                        newFilter();
                    }
                });
    }

    private void newFilter() {
    RowFilter<DefaultTableModel, Object> rf = null;
    //If current expression doesn't parse, don't update.
    try {
        rf = RowFilter.regexFilter(txt_search.getText(), 0);
    } catch (java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException e) {
        return;
    }
    sorter.setRowFilter(rf);
}
```

I really need some help, please! This is my last chance, because I really made the google search solutions, and nothing changed.

With respect,
Andrew

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- little modiefied code from JTable tutorial about filtering and sorting
- for filtering for JCheckBox you can to put "true" / "false"

code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableFilterSorter extends JPanel {

    private boolean DEBUG = false;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TableFilterSorter() {
        super(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        final JTextField filterCpText = new JTextField();
        filterCpText.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 28));
        filterCpText.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        filterCpText.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        JPanel filterCpPanel = new JPanel();
        filterCpPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        filterCpPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));
        filterCpPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        filterCpPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 30));
        filterCpPanel.add(filterCpText, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(filterCpPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        final JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 160));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        TableModel myTableModel = table.getModel();
        final TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(myTableModel);
        table.setRowSorter(sorter);
        filterCpText.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

            private void searchFieldChangedUpdate(DocumentEvent evt) {
                String text = filterCpText.getText();
                if (text.length() == 0) {
                    sorter.setRowFilter(null);
                    table.clearSelection();
                } else {
                    try {
                        sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text, 4));
                        table.clearSelection();
                    } catch (PatternSyntaxException pse) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bad regex pattern",
                                "Bad regex pattern", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent evt) {
                searchFieldChangedUpdate(evt);
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent evt) {
                searchFieldChangedUpdate(evt);
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent evt) {
                searchFieldChangedUpdate(evt);
            }
        });
    }

    private class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String[] columnNames = {"First Name", "Last Name", "Sport", "# of Years", "Vegetarian"};
        private Object[][] data = {
            {"Mary", "Campione", "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), false},
            {"Alison", "Huml", "Rowing", new Integer(3), true},
            {"Kathy", "Walrath", "Knitting", new Integer(2), false},
            {"Sharon", "Zakhour", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), true},
            {"Philip", "Milne", "Pool", new Integer(10), false},
            {"Mary", "Campione", "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), false},
            {"Alison", "Huml", "Rowing", new Integer(3), true},
            {"Kathy", "Walrath", "Knitting", new Integer(2), false},
            {"Sharon", "Zakhour", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), true},
            {"Philip", "Milne", "Pool", new Integer(10), false},};

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data[row][col];
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int c) {
            return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            if (col < 2) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("Setting value at " + row + "," + col
                        + " to " + value + " (an instance of " + value.getClass() + ")");
            }
            data[row][col] = value;
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("New value of data:");
                printDebugData();
            }
        }

        private void printDebugData() {
            int numRows = getRowCount();
            int numCols = getColumnCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
                System.out.print("    row " + i + ":");
                for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
                    System.out.print("  " + data[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println("--------------------------");
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        TableFilterSorter newContentPane = new TableFilterSorter();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
        frame.setLocation(150, 150);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as an additional pointer to most likely the most important difference: `table.setRowSorter(sorter);`, since the code in the question forgot that part.

Comment: I know this example, but you can help me to adapt on my needs. For now I use IDE to construct jTable, textFields and stuff. In the near future I plan to construct manually. I'm confused when I try to adapt that code to my jTable generated code with default model and stuff.

Comment: @Apopei Andrei Ionut sorry I'm don't know how to do it from built_in pallete, there are properties fields for every action, no reason on my side why to know Java & Swing and with GUI Editor too,