# How to get typed values of the combobox from keylistener

Tags: java, swing

How to get the typed values of the editable combobox in keypressed event? Please help me out. Please find my code:

```
comboInstrument.getEditor().getEditorComponent().addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println(comboInstrument.getSelectedItem().toString());
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
```

});

Comment: Posting your code so far is always helpful.

Comment: What's wrong with the well-known, pre-defined key bindings?

Comment: @trashgod I think that s/he wants to filtering key-typed, I asked OP for more infos..., then deleted my question

Comment: @mKorbel: Ah, a use case such as one using [`DocumentListener`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11578674/230513)?

Comment: a) don't use keyListeners ever - that's a special case of the general rule "always go for the highest abstraction available" because the higher abstraction will bundle a bunch of low-level stuff (f.i. in the keyListener you don't get pasted text) b) the selected item is changed only after committing the edit (that is after pressing enter or focus transfered away) c) describe your _real_ requirement to enable useful help

Comment: @trashgod thats right, exactly document(filter or listener) is used for most of autocompleted, but depends of / agreed with point c) by kleopatra

Comment: @kleopatra it there any book or some blogs, about advanced swing (complex interaction of components; threads; decoupling view from rest of app; etc.) that you can recommend?

Comment: @dantuch nothing I'm aware of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can able to get the typed key values through the following code. getSelectedItem is retrieving only the previous value selected and not the newly typed one. Thanks for ur responses friends.

```
comboInstrument.getEditor().getItem().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

**1.** When you type something in the JComboBox then press enter.

**2.** Use the `getSelectedItem()` to get the value, in the **actionPerfomed() Method of ActionListener Inteface.**

Comment: No, I'm getting the previously selected value of the combo box from getSelecteditem().

Answer (score 0):

You will need to cast the combos selected item:

```
    MyClass myClass = (MyClass)combo.getSelectedItem();
    // process myClass
```