# Search in JTable - not getting the correct output

Tags: java, regex, swing, search, jtable

I have a problem searching in my JTable. I found a method on Stack Overflow but it didn't seem to work. When I search now I get nothing.

To be honest I am not so good with reg. expressions.

The relevant code is in my searchTF keylistener but I wanted to show you the rest as well so you can get an idea of what I am trying to do.

I need to be able to search in my JTable.

[Implement search textField into jTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578578/implement-search-textfield-into-jtable)

This was the code I tried to implement. I have probably forgotten something.

```
package gui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

import domains.Member;
import mappers.MemberMapper;

public class ShowMembersGUI {
    private JFrame showMembersFrame;
    private JButton editMemberBtn, closeBtn, removeMemberBtn;
    private JTable table;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JPanel p;
    private Object id, fName, lName;
    private int index;
    private final MyTableModel myTableModel;
    private JTextField searchTF;
    private JLabel searchLbl;

    public ShowMembersGUI() {
        MemberMapper mMapper = new MemberMapper();
        List<Member> data = mMapper.selectAllMembers();
        myTableModel = new MyTableModel(data);

        table = new JTable(myTableModel);
        final TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(
                myTableModel);

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        table.setRowSorter(sorter);

        searchLbl = new JLabel("Søg");
        searchTF = new JTextField(10);
        searchTF.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {

                    searchTF.getDocument().addDocumentListener(
                            new DocumentListener() {

                                private void searchFieldChangedUpdate(
                                        DocumentEvent evt) {
                                    String text = searchTF.getText();
                                    if (text.length() == 0) {
                                        sorter.setRowFilter(null);
                                        table.clearSelection();
                                    } else {
                                        try {
                                            sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter
                                                    .regexFilter("(?i)" + text,
                                                            4));
                                            table.clearSelection();

                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent evt) {
                                    searchFieldChangedUpdate(evt);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent evt) {
                                    searchFieldChangedUpdate(evt);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent evt) {
                                    searchFieldChangedUpdate(evt);
                                }
                            });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        editMemberBtn = new JButton("Rediger Medlem");
        editMemberBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                EditMemberGUI editMemberGUI = new EditMemberGUI(
                        ShowMembersGUI.this);
                int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                // int column = table.getSelectedColumn();
                id = (Object) table.getValueAt(row, 0);
                Object fName = (Object) table.getValueAt(row, 1);
                Object lName = (Object) table.getValueAt(row, 2);
                Object address = (Object) table.getValueAt(row, 3);
                Object zipCode = (Object) table.getValueAt(row, 4);
                Object city = (Object) table.getValueAt(row, 5);
                Object email = (Object) table.getValueAt(row, 6);
                Object phoneNo = (Object) table.getValueAt(row, 7);

                index = (Integer) id;
                editMemberGUI.getfNameTF().setText(fName.toString());
                editMemberGUI.getlNameTF().setText(lName.toString());
                editMemberGUI.getAddressTF().setText(address.toString());
                editMemberGUI.getZipCodeTF().setText(zipCode.toString());
                editMemberGUI.getCityTF().setText(city.toString());
                editMemberGUI.getEmailTF().setText(email.toString());
                editMemberGUI.getPhoneNoTF().setText(phoneNo.toString());
                editMemberGUI.showGUI();

            }
        });

        removeMemberBtn = new JButton("Fjern Medlem");
        removeMemberBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                // int column = table.getSelectedColumn();
                id = (Object) table.getValueAt(row, 0);
                fName = (Object) table.getValueAt(row, 1);
                lName = (Object) table.getValueAt(row, 2);

                Object[] options = { "Ja", "Nej" };
                int n = JOptionPane
                        .showOptionDialog(null,
                                "Er du sikker du vil slette medlem?\n\n"
                                        + "Medlemsnr: " + id + "\n\n" + fName
                                        + " " + lName, "Advarsel",
                                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options,
                                options[0]);

                if (n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    MemberMapper mMapper = new MemberMapper();
                    int i = (Integer) id;
                    mMapper.removeMember(i);
                    myTableModel.removeMemberFromTable(row);
                    myTableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
                } else {
                }

            }
        });

        closeBtn = new JButton("Close");
        closeBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                showMembersFrame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });

        p = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));

        p1.add(searchLbl);
        p1.add(searchTF);
        p2.add(editMemberBtn);
        p2.add(removeMemberBtn);
        p2.add(closeBtn);

        p.add(p1);
        p.add(p2);

    }

    public void showGUI() {
        showMembersFrame = new JFrame();
        showMembersFrame.setTitle("Vis Medlemmer");
        showMembersFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        showMembersFrame.setSize(1000, 600);

        showMembersFrame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        showMembersFrame.add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        // showMembersFrame.pack();
        showMembersFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    public void setIndex(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    public JTable getTable() {
        return table;
    }

    public void setTable(JTable table) {
        this.table = table;
    }

}

class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private List<Member> members = new ArrayList<Member>();

    public MyTableModel(List<Member> members) {
        this.members = members;
    }

    public void addMember(Member m) {
        members.add(m);
        int row = members.size() - 1;
        fireTableRowsInserted(row, row);
    }

    public void removeMemberFromTable(int row) {
        members.remove(row);
        fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
    }

    public void tableUpdate(int row, Member m) {
        if (row >= 0 && row < members.size()) {
            members.set(row, m);
            fireTableRowsUpdated(row, row);
        }
    }

    public List<Member> getMembers() {
        return new ArrayList<Member>(members);
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 8;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return members.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Member m = members.get(rowIndex);

        switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            return m.getMemberId();

        case 1:
            return m.getfName();

        case 2:
            return m.getlName();

        case 3:
            return m.getAddress();

        case 4:
            return m.getZipCode();

        case 5:
            return m.getCity();

        case 6:
            return m.getEmail();

        case 7:
            return m.getPhoneNo();

        default:
            return "";
        }
    }

    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        switch (column) {
        case 0:
            return "MedlemsID";

        case 1:
            return "Fornavn";

        case 2:
            return "Efternavn";

        case 3:
            return "Adresse";

        case 4:
            return "Postnummer";

        case 5:
            return "By";

        case 6:
            return "Email";

        case 7:
            return "Telefonnr";
        default:
            return "";
        }
    }

    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            return String.class;

        case 1:
            return String.class;

        case 2:
            return String.class;

        case 3:
            return String.class;

        case 4:
            return String.class;

        case 5:
            return String.class;

        case 6:
            return String.class;

        case 7:
            return String.class;

        default:
            return String.class;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for JTable, XxxTableModel to local variable instead of 3rd. side or custom classes, before anything to read offical Oracle tutotial How to use Tables, search here about XxxTableModel based on util.List, remove KeyListener and use only events from DocumentListener

Comment: Ok I am removing the KeyListener now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem in next poor designed code:

```
  searchTF.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {

                searchTF.getDocument().addDocumentListener(
                        new DocumentListener() {

                            private void searchFieldChangedUpdate(
                                    DocumentEvent evt) {
                                String text = searchTF.getText();
                                if (text.length() == 0) {
                                    sorter.setRowFilter(null);
                                } else {
                                    try {
                                        sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text,4));
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent evt) {
                                searchFieldChangedUpdate(evt);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent evt) {
                                searchFieldChangedUpdate(evt);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent evt) {
                                searchFieldChangedUpdate(evt);
                            }
                        });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

At First, use `DocumentListener` instead of `KeyListener` as recommended by @mKorbel.

Second, as I see you only need to use search when `ENTER` is pressed, for that you can use [keyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) .

And, `searchTF.getDocument().addDocumentListener(...)` this code in your class add a new `DocumentListener` to your field, do it once at construction of field.

Use next code for your purposes:

```
    InputMap im = searchTF.getInputMap(JTextField.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    ActionMap am = searchTF.getActionMap();
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "ENTER");
    am.put("ENTER", new AbstractAction() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
             String text = searchTF.getText();
             if (text.isEmpty()) {
                 sorter.setRowFilter(null);
             } else {
                 try {
                     sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text, 4));
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
             }
        }
    });
```

Comment: +1 for .... - 1mio for my bu**s**ts e.g. table.clearSelection();, note this is standard reason for donwnvoting by kleopatra or camickr in my posts, be sure both will add nice comment :-)

Comment: remove that, really I copy method from question, only change `==0` to `isEmpty()` :)

Comment: I removed that and changed == 0 to .isEmpty() but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Actually I don't want the enter button to be the trigger. It would be nice if you just type and it filters automatically.

Comment: @ilhami If you want to serch by entering text, use only document listener: replace `searchTF.addKeyListener(...)` by `searchTF.getDocument().addDocumentListener(...)` and all will be work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was.

It was this line. I had set the value to 4. :)

```
sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text, 4));
```

I tried this but it's like they overwrite each other.

```
sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text, 0));
sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text, 1));
sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text, 2));
```

But I can only search for one at a time. When copy/paste that line to write different values in that parameter it only filters on the last of those lines.

UPDATE:

```
sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text, 0, 1, 2));
```

This worked. Thanks!

Comment: But I can only search for one at a time. When copy/paste that line to write different values in that parameter it only filters on the last of those lines.